# How can I transform coordinate systems based on quaternion data?

Tags: transformation, coordinate-systems, quaternions

I have a single rigid body object, and its orientations in quaternion with respect to two coordinate systems, each is called original and prime, respectively; therefore, I have two quaternions $\mathbf{q} =<q_w, q_x, q_y, q_z>$ and $\mathbf{q'} =<q'_w, q'_x, q'_y, q'_z>$. See picture:

[image]

I'd like to find a transformation between two coordinate systems from the known values $\mathbf{q}$, and $\mathbf{q'}$. 
By doing that, I want to transform $\mathbf{q'}$ to the values with respect to original coordinate.

I'm not very familiar with quaternion, but the measurement systems I have give orientation values only in quaternion.

I saw following post, but it won't helpful to my problem. 
[How can I transform coordinate systems with quaternions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/727793/how-can-i-transform-coordinate-systems-with-quaternions)

Could anyone help me please? Thank you :)

Comment: I'm not sure to well understand your question.
My interpretation is that you have a vector (the black vector in your illustration)  that is represented as a pure imaginary quaternion  $q=(0,q_x,q_y,q_z)$ in a reference systems $O$ ( note that $q_w=0$) . You know that the other system $O'$ is obtained from $O$ by a rotation of a given angle around a given axis and you want to know the quaternion representation  $q'=(0,q'_x,q'_y,q'_z)$ of the same vector in this system $O'$. It's all right?